# Cell border stays open at the end?

Tags: html, css, jsp

[image]

See how the cell border at the end stays open like that.  What's the cause? Here's the code:

```
<td class="center" style="width: 50%;">
    <table class="heading_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Workload Year</th>
            <td>${scenario.workloadYear}</td>
            <th>SORs</th>
            <td class=”wrappable”> 
            <c:forEach items="${scenario.sorCodesNames}" var="item" varStatus="status"> 
            ${item}
            <c:if test= "${!status.last}">,</c:if>
            </c:forEach>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <th style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal;" colspan="6">
                Last modified by <strong>${scenario.auditable.lastModifiedBy.lastName}, ${scenario.auditable.lastModifiedBy.firstName}</strong>
                on <fmt:formatDate value="${scenario.auditable.lastModifiedDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" />
            </th>

    </table>
```

.

```
/* Style applied to all header cells within a heading_table. */
table.heading_table th
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border: #999999 1px solid;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
/* Style applied to all data cells within a heading_table. */
table.heading_table td
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border: #999999 1px solid;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: btw...I added "wrappable" after the problem...so thats not the cause :)

Comment: please show the css for .heading_table

Comment: It's probably somethign to do with the CSS applied to the table, you should post the relevent code for that as well.

Comment: You should provide the CSS that goes along with this.  There is no border defined in the posted code.

Comment: Can you provide the CSS for your site as well? Also, your HTML is bad - you've got a `<th>` without a `<tr>` around it and it also has a `colspan` value that doesn't match the number of columns in your table.

Comment: For what is the `margin` in your table cells? At best, they have no effect, at worst, this is what is causing this problem.

Comment: What browser/OS are you seeing this in? And also, what other CSS do you have that could be affecting your table and table cells? I get cellspacing when I create a test page with this HTML and CSS and I don't get your problem with the border.

Comment: I changed the colspans to "4" instead of "6" and added another ste of <tr> like in the example below.....????

Comment: seems to work...lol..I never really been a UI person...more java stuff...so I have to work on this from time to time

Comment: Thanks for all of the contributions...got me to get it working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td class="center" style="width: 50%;">
<table class="heading_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Workload Year</th>
        <td>${scenario.workloadYear}</td>
        <th>SORs</th>
        <td class=”wrappable”> 
        <c:forEach items="${scenario.sorCodesNames}" var="item" varStatus="status"> 
        ${item}
        <c:if test= "${!status.last}">,</c:if>
        </c:forEach>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal;" colspan="6">
            Last modified by <strong>${scenario.auditable.lastModifiedBy.lastName}, ${scenario.auditable.lastModifiedBy.firstName}</strong>
            on <fmt:formatDate value="${scenario.auditable.lastModifiedDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" />
        </th>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hmmmm I closed that tr and added another one...still open cell??